# Is there a way to change about:config DOM value for only one website in firefox

Tags: firefox, dom

I would like to allow one website to use the window.resizeTo(); function but disallow all the other websites from doing that... I wonder if there is any way to do that even if its difficult.

even if its not in the firefox original settings maybe there is an addon that will allow for it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file called `user.js` in your profile directory. Most Firefox preferences are kept in a file called `prefs.js` - but the browser can write to this file, and often overwrite any changes.

*If* user.js can accept `if-else` logic and access the current URL, you could very easily establish logic to turn preferences on and off depending upon the URL.

[I found this information here](http://www.patheticcockroach.com/mpam4/?p=55).

#### Update

As far as I can see, `user.js` is only read when the browser loads - so the method described above won't work :( The best way to achieve required functionality would be to use/write/invent a *Firefox addon*.

Comment: ok sounds great but... I am using arora and i cannot find prefs.js is it the same file as channel-prefs.js ?? and second i dont have user.js is it because i am using arora or do i need to create a user first and then use aurora with that user?

Comment: As I updated, it's unlikely the method I initially described will work. Why did you tag the question with `Firefox` if you're using Arora?

Comment: because i want this functionality in firefox (also aurora is firefox just a pre-release version)

Comment: I guess that's where spelling counts: [arora](http://code.google.com/p/arora/) and [aurora](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/#aurora/aurora-desktop) are two different browsers.

Comment: I think i must finally give up on this wild goose chase... I just wonder if there is a good description how user.js works because i cant find it anywhere.

Comment: To be honest, I'm surprise to see there's no addon that does this (that I could find) - it's not that tough to write, and seems like it could be a common request. I do wonder though if the limitation lies in the browser - some preferences simply will not kick-in until the browser restarts.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that the `about:config` preferences are that granular. You can either set a preference value to `true` for the entire browser, or `false` for the entire browser. But you cannot define case-by-case values.

Source: [http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox...config_Entries#DOM.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries#DOM.)

This limitation is illustrated through the options of the browser as well (all or none):

[image]